# Where can we find a list of chalek/chapter lengths from shortest to longest of Tanakh?

Tags: sources-mekorot

A quick glance of Bereshis alone would make chapter 24 the longest. Everyone knows Tehillim 119 is the longest of all of Tanakh.

We are looking for a list of at least the Torah shortest to longest. All of Tanakh would be stellar. Google searches are unclear if its counting by English or Hebrew.

Comment: What does this have to do with Judaism? You're asking about a Christian statistic. You could always make this question about secular knowledge on topic by motivating it by a desire to practice Judaism. Do you want this list for some reason related to Judaism?

Comment: "Today, a standard edition of Sefer Tehillim has 150 chapters, but Maseches Sofrim (16:11), among other sources, says there are only 147, corresponding to the years of the life of Yaakov Avinu. This doesn’t mean three psalms were added later. The Gemara (Berachos 9b) tells us that Psalms 1 and 2 used to be one long psalm.

The Aleppo Codex, the oldest complete manuscript of Tanach that we know of, joins together Psalms 114 and 115. Minchas Shai suggests that Psalms 116 and 117 were also sometimes joined together. " https://mishpacha.com/tehillim-minhagim-and-mysteries/

Comment: I voted to close this, because the current chapter divisions don't have much to do with Judaism. Psalms would be a better question, but there Psalm 119 is clearly the longest (and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psalm_119) claims that that's the longest chapter in the Tanakh).

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't know who made the current chapter divisions we use. Though they are based on the Christian division, they aren't 100% the same. I think there's a question somewhere around here about this.

Comment: @Harel one of the first major printed bibles for a jewish audience in hebrew copied in the christian divisions and made a few typos. That's the "jewish" chapter system. But as you can see it's not actually jewish in any way related to Judaism

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to go native and eschew the chapter system (non-Jewish origin), you can sort all פרשיות פתוחות\סתומות in Tanach in ascending or descending size order by # of verses, # or words or # of letters at https://basehasefer.com/#/parshaViewer (*my own site*).

When hovering over sortable column headers, a hand-shaped mouse pointer will appear.  Clicking once will sort the rows according to that column in ascending order. Clicking again will sort the rows in descending order.  Clicking once more will return the rows to their original sort order as specified in the search settings on the right side of the screen.  Sortable columns can be used for best effect when the option to **Show All Results** is selected at the bottom-left corner of the grid.

So for sorting here, click the פסוקים column to sort by pasuk amount.
order:

[image]

Ascending order here can get confusing at the beginning of the list since there are parshios that start mid-pasuk and don't occupy a complete pasuk and I display a count of zero.

Perhaps in the future I will offer an option to view a breakdown of Tanach by chapter.

Comment: On my computer (Windows 10, Chrome and Edge), the headers don't align with the columns, and they scroll in opposite directions.

Comment: @magicker72 - What version of Chrome and Edge are you using?

Comment: Chrome 100.0.4896.75 64-bit and Edge 100.0.1185.36 64-bit. But anyway, this is not a tech troubleshooting site, I just wanted any other users to know that it's not only them, if they have issues.

Comment: OK, thx - looks like you're up to date - works for me but things I have seen things get quirky on the grid for other reasons - will keep my eyes open for other reports of this.

Comment: What version of Tanakh are you using

Comment: It's based on this project: מקרא על פי המסורה: The Mikra al Pi HaMasora project at WikiText/WikiSource available at: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mkQyj6by1AtBUabpbaxaZq9Z2X3pX8ZpwG91ZCSOEYs/edit#gid=920165745
That project bases itself on the Aleppo Codex wherever possible.

The full list of sources appears in the Sources tab of the About popup screen.  That popup is accessible by clicking the icon with a white letter i inside a blue circle that can be found in the upper right of the screen or in the system menu.

Comment: BTW - most mistakes in text or structuring on my site are likely due to my own errors from incorrectly parsing the source material.  I hope to remedy those in the future.  An error pertinent to the parsha listing in question here is my mistaken combining of some perakim in Tehillim that are not separated by a standard parsha break but at the points where Tehillim is broken into sub-seforim eg. at the beginning of perakim 42, 73, 90, 107.

Answer (score 0):

For English, KJV, sorted by Verse count:

```
verses,words,bytes,bookchapter
2,35,179,Psalms117
3,96,503,Esther10
3,63,314,Psalms131
3,72,381,Psalms133
3,47,229,Psalms134
4,98,487,Psalms123
5,161,822,Hosea3
5,157,781,Jeremiah45
5,91,471,Psalms100
5,113,587,Psalms125
5,115,551,Psalms127
5,104,571,Psalms15
5,135,646,Psalms43
5,107,529,Psalms70
5,97,532,Psalms93
6,96,452,Job25
6,140,708,Isaiah12
6,175,938,Isaiah20
6,215,1083,Isaiah4
6,189,947,Malachi4
6,136,697,Psalms1
6,100,540,Psalms126
6,107,547,Psalms128
6,113,564,Psalms13
6,91,506,Psalms150
6,124,614,Psalms23
6,158,830,Psalms53
7,262,1373,Isaiah18
7,222,1173,Jeremiah47
7,135,719,Psalms11
7,149,743,Psalms110
7,95,458,Psalms120
7,156,802,Psalms14
7,158,785,Psalms142
7,117,573,Psalms54
7,118,594,Psalms67
7,120,617,Psalms87
8,297,1513,1Chronicles20
8,213,1014,Ezekiel15
8,276,1446,Isaiah39
8,270,1391,Leviticus12
8,181,876,Psalms101
8,155,803,Psalms12
8,118,596,Psalms121
8,129,603,Psalms124
8,127,646,Psalms129
8,180,920,Psalms138
8,114,608,Psalms114
8,124,630,Psalms130
8,147,721,Psalms3
8,173,853,Psalms4
8,141,684,Psalms61
8,124,639,Psalms82
9,253,1299,2Chronicles27
9,241,1213,Hosea14
9,275,1444,Isaiah15
9,331,1683,Isaiah31
9,317,1694,Joshua20
9,151,736,Psalms113
9,133,675,Psalms122
9,174,880,Psalms137
9,152,793,Psalms149
9,153,780,Psalms20
9,210,1086,Psalms28
9,152,784,Psalms47
9,174,923,Psalms52
9,175,884,Psalms8
9,179,929,Psalms98
9,166,894,Psalms99
9,346,1714,Zechariah13
10,283,1413,Ecclesiastes11
10,355,1824,Esther7
10,334,1713,Exodus11
10,283,1465,Ezekiel2
10,287,1512,Isaiah35
10,371,1864,Jeremiah24
10,224,1117,Jonah2
10,270,1379,Jonah3
10,263,1451,Joshua16
10,187,997,Psalms111
10,182,1009,Psalms112
10,213,1069,Psalms141
10,188,965,Psalms146
10,188,944,Psalms24
10,169,838,Psalms6
10,194,1023,Psalms64
10,199,977,Psalms75
10,306,1563,Zechariah3
11,432,2218,1Samuel29
11,363,1922,2Chronicles19
11,411,2084,Ezekiel9
11,382,2018,Ezra1
11,366,1817,Hosea1
11,265,1319,Hosea6
11,376,1894,Isaiah50
11,391,2110,Isaiah61
11,343,1686,Jonah4
11,401,2133,Nehemiah1
11,217,1085,Psalms16
11,190,977,Psalms29
11,215,1091,Psalms46
11,205,1023,Psalms63
11,252,1298,Psalms32
11,291,1425,Psalms42
11,240,1203,Psalms57
11,229,1164,Psalms58
11,210,998,Psalms95
11,298,1487,So
11,349,1717,Zechariah5
12,397,2051,1Samuel27
12,451,2237,1Samuel5
12,456,2354,2Chronicles22
12,446,2304,2Samuel4
12,332,1632,Deuteronomy34
12,313,1532,Ecclesiastes6
12,320,1606,Hosea11
12,393,1940,Isaiah25
12,399,2037,Isaiah53
12,373,1952,Isaiah56
12,374,1930,Isaiah62
12,320,1711,Isaiah64
12,366,1865,Micah3
12,264,1319,Psalms143
12,218,1116,Psalms2
12,195,990,Psalms26
12,243,1171,Psalms30
12,235,1232,Psalms36
12,257,1353,Psalms5
12,223,1136,Psalms60
12,240,1212,Psalms62
12,205,1040,Psalms76
12,238,1182,Psalms84
12,201,1103,Psalms97
12,420,2121,Zechariah10
13,400,2043,Job2
13,361,1927,1Samuel31
13,421,2151,2Samuel9
13,445,2352,Amos4
13,424,2128,Daniel12
13,560,2990,Ezra3
13,418,2096,Isaiah27
13,355,1801,Isaiah46
13,412,2087,Isaiah55
13,379,1870,Isaiah6
13,473,2408,Jeremiah43
13,398,1974,Judges17
13,413,2109,Micah2
13,489,2460,Micah4
13,384,2031,Nahum2
13,348,1829,Numbers17
13,458,2506,Numbers36
13,219,1101,Psalms108
13,252,1322,Psalms140
13,259,1360,Psalms21
13,283,1386,Psalms39
13,253,1294,Psalms41
13,238,1155,Psalms56
13,280,1547,Psalms65
13,290,1548,Psalms79
13,220,1157,Psalms85
13,239,1232,Psalms96
13,295,1528,So
13,305,1529,So
13,330,1649,Zechariah2
14,220,1171,Job26
14,378,2008,1Chronicles10
14,400,2054,1Chronicles13
14,493,2520,2Chronicles16
14,511,2676,2Chronicles5
14,413,2116,Amos6
14,428,2086,Amos8
14,386,1999,Ecclesiastes12
14,506,2564,Esther5
14,490,2567,Esther6
14,370,1877,Ezekiel19
14,484,2504,Ezekiel6
14,325,1695,Hosea12
14,344,1784,Hosea8
14,429,2289,Isaiah16
14,442,2283,Isaiah17
14,535,2754,Isaiah58
14,512,2613,Jeremiah21
14,501,2540,Malachi1
14,216,1130,Psalms148
14,286,1515,Psalms19
14,354,1719,Psalms27
14,243,1222,Psalms48
14,374,1887,So
14,476,2502,Zechariah12
14,379,1929,Zechariah4
14,392,2050,Zechariah7
15,518,2644,1Samuel11
15,514,2624,1Samuel21
15,463,2395,2Chronicles14
15,470,2539,Amos1
15,412,2069,Amos3
15,564,2823,Amos9
15,567,3060,Esther3
15,417,2149,Ezekiel35
15,632,3318,Ezra9
15,466,2350,Haggai1
15,440,2359,Hosea10
15,383,2001,Hosea5
15,486,2597,Isaiah47
15,420,2230,Isaiah52
15,556,2887,Jeremiah19
15,500,2615,Joshua14
15,565,2912,Joshua5
15,414,2242,Judges12
15,462,2343,Micah5
15,409,2138,Nahum1
15,317,1660,Psalms144
15,326,1667,Psalms17
15,273,1406,Psalms92
15,439,2230,Zechariah6
15,478,2570,Zephaniah2
16,278,1376,Job17
16,270,1427,Job35
16,497,2746,2Chronicles12
16,457,2396,Amos2
16,396,2019,Ecclesiastes4
16,481,2465,Exodus17
16,428,2183,Genesis16
16,442,2239,Hosea13
16,414,2215,Hosea7
16,535,2727,Isaiah11
16,697,3633,Jeremiah40
16,590,2970,Joshua23
16,569,2938,Leviticus17
16,502,2563,Leviticus2
16,468,2444,Micah1
16,456,2383,Micah6
16,400,2064,Numbers12
16,519,2642,Numbers30
16,304,1558,Psalms81
16,304,1546,Psalms91
16,379,2002,So
16,413,2069,So
17,297,1482,Job23
17,458,2358,Job42
17,374,2024,1Chronicles14
17,527,2803,1Samuel7
17,548,2918,2Chronicles1
17,498,2627,2Chronicles3
17,488,2470,Amos7
17,532,2646,Ecclesiastes8
17,534,2837,Esther4
17,667,3522,Esther8
17,524,2778,Ezekiel25
17,536,2763,Ezekiel4
17,645,3318,Ezekiel5
17,600,3141,Ezra5
17,440,2420,Habakkuk1
17,485,2576,Hosea9
17,434,2272,Isaiah21
17,539,2809,Isaiah34
17,510,2714,Isaiah54
17,561,2962,Jeremiah12
17,557,2938,Jeremiah28
17,531,2603,Jonah1
17,583,2982,Joshua3
17,542,2708,Leviticus1
17,528,2661,Leviticus3
17,563,2906,Malachi2
17,417,2143,Psalms40
17,344,1890,Psalms45
17,356,1771,Psalms59
17,344,1776,Psalms7
17,329,1633,Psalms86
17,337,1725,Psalms90
17,343,1762,So
17,368,1821,So
17,519,2550,Zechariah11
17,553,2778,Zechariah9
18,444,2516,1Chronicles18
18,616,3282,1Chronicles19
18,545,2890,1Kings5
18,663,3441,2Chronicles2
18,554,2967,2Chronicles8
18,687,3403,2Kings1
18,465,2569,2Samuel8
18,645,3274,Deuteronomy13
18,398,2109,Ecclesiastes1
18,573,2843,Ecclesiastes9
18,510,2529,Exodus24
18,456,2382,Exodus31
18,698,3527,Ezekiel31
18,673,3363,Ezekiel8
18,475,2385,Genesis13
18,516,2664,Genesis20
18,487,2590,Isaiah23
18,612,3166,Jeremiah20
18,563,2969,Jeremiah39
18,682,3554,Jeremiah41
18,591,3109,Joshua1
18,678,3640,Joshua17
18,491,2615,Judges10
18,583,2987,Malachi3
18,704,3743,Nehemiah8
18,463,2431,Numbers25
18,306,1575,Proverbs9
18,368,1906,Psalms10
18,292,1465,Psalms115
18,294,1487,Psalms132
18,291,1525,Psalms83
18,314,1611,Psalms88
18,559,2738,Ruth3
18,573,2925,Zephaniah1
19,623,3188,1Chronicles22
19,579,3029,2Chronicles10
19,537,2729,2Chronicles15
19,478,2638,2Chronicles17
19,627,3315,2Samuel10
19,581,2944,Deuteronomy25
19,686,3551,Deuteronomy26
19,508,2711,Habakkuk3
19,484,2664,Hosea4
19,557,2947,Isaiah63
19,547,2754,Jeremiah1
19,676,3495,Jeremiah35
19,742,3736,Leviticus5
19,538,2903,Nahum3
19,656,3401,Nehemiah5
19,621,3166,Nehemiah6
19,306,1507,Psalms116
19,353,1783,Psalms80
19,341,1836,Psalms51
20,357,1862,Job11
20,643,3387,2Chronicles21
20,676,3502,2Kings16
20,732,3797,2Kings22
20,604,3222,2Kings24
20,844,4170,2Kings7
20,727,3770,Deuteronomy17
20,666,3422,Deuteronomy20
20,685,3432,Deuteronomy30
20,586,3046,Deuteronomy8
20,422,2163,Ecclesiastes10
20,553,2780,Ecclesiastes5
20,588,3215,Ezekiel42
20,556,2802,Genesis12
20,559,2811,Genesis23
20,528,2702,Genesis33
20,583,2989,Habakkuk2
20,456,2416,Isaiah32
20,528,2744,Joel1
20,726,3598,Judges14
20,668,3375,Judges15
20,648,3373,Leviticus10
20,603,3084,Micah7
20,738,3662,Nehemiah2
20,319,1683,Psalms147
20,357,1899,Psalms49
20,347,1763,Psalms66
20,389,2037,Psalms72
20,350,1772,Psalms77
20,387,2020,Psalms9
20,618,3190,Zephaniah3
21,363,1863,Job18
21,357,1900,Job4
21,415,2043,Job7
21,885,4511,1Chronicles28
21,753,3767,1Kings19
21,570,2808,1Samuel3
21,772,3965,1Samuel6
21,809,4162,2Chronicles23
21,778,4249,2Chronicles31
21,759,3838,2Kings11
21,710,3661,2Kings12
21,680,3460,2Kings20
21,610,3283,Daniel1
21,668,3379,Daniel10
21,629,3251,Deuteronomy19
21,579,3073,Exodus27
21,748,3754,Ezekiel26
21,735,3729,Ezekiel29
21,492,2497,Genesis15
21,571,2937,Isaiah26
21,590,3074,Isaiah57
21,611,3335,Isaiah59
21,620,3272,Isaiah9
21,723,3617,Jeremiah15
21,720,3774,Jeremiah16
21,632,3381,Jeremiah37
21,588,3103,Joel3
21,690,3653,Obadiah1
21,350,1794,Psalms135
21,352,1808,Psalms145
21,643,3328,Zechariah1
21,775,3937,Zechariah14
22,663,3423,Job1
22,424,2153,Job10
22,432,2175,Job14
22,396,1989,Job16
22,397,2075,Job32
22,362,1907,Job8
22,683,3445,1Samuel24
22,755,3834,1Samuel4
22,563,2880,1Samuel8
22,664,3583,2Chronicles13
22,616,3194,2Chronicles4
22,770,4037,2Chronicles7
22,800,4173,2Samuel21
22,703,3537,Deuteronomy24
22,626,3169,Deuteronomy10
22,731,3826,Deuteronomy16
22,633,3209,Deuteronomy18
22,539,2579,Ecclesiastes3
22,738,3994,Esther1
22,479,2558,Exodus1
22,697,3536,Exodus13
22,813,4034,Exodus3
22,681,3494,Ezekiel10
22,800,4265,Ezra6
22,643,3195,Genesis28
22,661,3407,Genesis48
22,601,3009,Genesis6
22,608,3081,Genesis8
22,598,3134,Isaiah13
22,589,2984,Isaiah2
22,712,3642,Isaiah36
22,614,2987,Isaiah38
22,649,3297,Isaiah48
22,687,3604,Isaiah60
22,580,3029,Isaiah8
22,710,3724,Jeremiah14
22,784,4035,Jeremiah27
22,846,4464,Jeremiah34
22,796,3891,Jeremiah42
22,728,3773,Jeremiah8
22,781,4232,Lamentations1
22,905,4704,Lamentations2
22,620,3305,Lamentations4
22,318,1656,Lamentations5
22,705,3668,Numbers19
22,331,1814,Proverbs2
22,364,1924,Psalms103
22,364,1804,Psalms25
22,372,1881,Psalms33
22,369,1851,Psalms34
22,383,1902,Psalms38
22,671,3362,Ruth1
22,643,3254,Ruth4
23,396,1984,Job27
23,722,3914,1Samuel13
23,703,3589,1Samuel16
23,785,3973,1Samuel22
23,509,2793,2Chronicles11
23,744,3951,2Chronicles26
23,764,4021,2Chronicles36
23,761,3867,2Samuel16
23,736,3739,2Samuel6
23,729,3713,Deuteronomy15
23,754,3781,Deuteronomy21
23,829,4470,Esther2
23,733,3627,Exodus33
23,617,3216,Exodus5
23,761,3916,Ezekiel13
23,769,3979,Ezekiel14
23,799,4078,Ezekiel38
23,803,4222,Ezekiel47
23,689,3353,Genesis39
23,603,3112,Genesis40
23,702,3519,Haggai2
23,701,3480,Hosea2
23,615,3256,Isaiah24
23,794,4038,Isaiah51
23,772,3957,Jeremiah11
23,682,3444,Jeremiah18
23,740,3905,Joshua11
23,715,3756,Judges2
23,574,2944,Leviticus24
23,739,3771,Nehemiah4
23,633,3331,Numbers27
23,745,3896,Numbers9
23,377,1944,Proverbs5
23,423,2227,Psalms50
23,458,2333,Psalms55
23,436,2351,Psalms74
23,379,2017,Psalms94
23,786,3953,Ruth2
23,726,3603,Zechariah8
24,426,2201,Job37
24,385,1957,Job40
24,371,2154,1Chronicles3
24,704,3407,1Kings17
24,720,3734,1Samuel19
24,825,4227,Ezekiel17
24,903,4560,Ezekiel46
24,793,4243,Ezra4
24,630,3327,Genesis14
24,653,3299,Genesis22
24,719,3500,Genesis3
24,608,3090,Genesis7
24,766,3953,Isaiah29
24,609,3351,Isaiah33
24,834,4293,Isaiah66
24,824,4202,Jeremiah26
24,741,3846,Jeremiah30
24,510,2635,Joshua12
24,792,3979,Joshua2
24,730,3764,Joshua4
24,785,4015,Judges4
24,611,3058,Leviticus21
24,648,3401,Leviticus9
24,405,2148,Proverbs18
24,434,2200,Psalms139
24,522,2629,Psalms31
24,495,2501,Psalms71
25,424,2238,Job12
25,506,2586,Job24
25,429,2069,Job29
25,796,4030,1Samuel12
25,874,4456,1Samuel26
25,860,4438,1Samuel28
25,805,4150,2Chronicles33
25,800,4157,2Kings13
25,873,4333,2Kings2
25,880,4519,2Samuel24
25,649,3465,2Samuel5
25,710,3674,Deuteronomy23
25,668,3417,Deuteronomy6
25,727,3726,Exodus19
25,682,3410,Exodus2
25,717,3712,Exodus7
25,747,3763,Ezekiel11
25,908,4738,Ezekiel45
25,657,3186,Genesis2
25,755,3883,Isaiah19
25,701,3558,Isaiah22
25,701,3550,Isaiah42
25,799,4097,Isaiah45
25,778,4023,Isaiah65
25,718,3600,Isaiah7
25,699,3556,Jeremiah10
25,827,4388,Jeremiah3
25,790,3867,Judges13
25,765,4000,Judges21
25,977,5104,Judges7
25,684,3527,Numbers24
25,425,2331,Proverbs13
26,460,2285,Job3
26,690,3715,1Chronicles5
26,772,3955,2Kings21
26,874,4389,2Samuel20
26,625,3273,Deuteronomy27
26,869,4558,Deuteronomy7
26,760,3783,Ecclesiastes2
26,587,2992,Exodus20
26,835,4293,Ezekiel28
26,786,3900,Ezekiel30
26,828,4352,Ezekiel41
26,658,3308,Genesis4
26,712,3725,Genesis50
26,613,3240,Isaiah3
26,893,4566,Isaiah49
26,867,4487,Jeremiah33
26,798,4226,Jeremiah9
26,953,4946,Joshua7
26,713,3888,Numbers8
26,379,1958,Psalms136
26,477,2446,Psalms44
27,473,2485,Job5
27,806,4086,1Chronicles17
27,890,4556,1Samuel10
27,1017,4951,1Samuel9
27,960,4988,2Chronicles24
27,923,4855,2Chronicles28
27,896,4950,2Chronicles30
27,927,5073,2Chronicles35
27,875,4479,2Kings3
27,1002,5055,2Kings5
27,740,3773,2Samuel1
27,841,4256,2Samuel11
27,685,3514,Amos5
27,880,4467,Daniel8
27,993,5344,Daniel9
27,740,3863,Exodus15
27,787,4008,Exodus18
27,802,3911,Ezekiel24
27,836,4197,Ezekiel3
27,934,4778,Ezekiel43
27,795,4150,Ezekiel7
27,706,3647,Genesis17
27,766,3951,Jeremiah13
27,856,4412,Jeremiah17
27,930,4804,Joshua6
27,827,4250,Joshua9
27,863,4484,Leviticus20
27,769,4028,Numbers6
27,487,2542,Proverbs27
27,452,2449,Proverbs29
27,445,2271,Proverbs4
27,438,2224,Proverbs7
28,441,2202,Job13
28,483,2456,Job28
28,878,4450,1Kings3
28,854,4485,1Kings9
28,810,4056,1Samuel1
28,998,5224,2Chronicles25
28,933,4990,Daniel6
28,954,4939,Daniel7
28,898,4630,Ezekiel1
28,827,4169,Ezekiel12
28,898,4549,Ezekiel37
28,891,4571,Ezra7
28,759,3836,Genesis45
28,739,3795,Isaiah43
28,914,4794,Isaiah44
28,1012,5210,Jeremiah38
28,849,4455,Jeremiah46
28,798,4347,Joshua18
28,504,2677,Proverbs12
28,504,2671,Proverbs17
28,550,2772,Proverbs25
28,487,2442,Proverbs26
28,556,2945,Proverbs28
28,483,2443,Psalms102
28,592,3096,Psalms35
28,451,2345,Psalms73
29,504,2508,Job19
29,550,2797,Job20
29,743,4006,1Chronicles15
29,868,4502,1Kings10
29,937,4811,1Kings21
29,860,4454,1Samuel23
29,910,4678,2Kings14
29,982,4943,2Kings8
29,964,5031,2Samuel17
29,887,4467,2Samuel7
29,736,3698,Deuteronomy14
29,880,4463,Deuteronomy29
29,844,4353,Deuteronomy3
29,834,4304,Deuteronomy33
29,992,5172,Deuteronomy9
29,646,3277,Ecclesiastes7
29,928,4657,Exodus10
29,767,3825,Exodus37
29,957,4859,Ezekiel39
29,693,3552,Genesis35
29,687,3459,Genesis9
29,842,4401,Isaiah28
29,833,4315,Isaiah41
29,820,4283,Numbers20
29,659,3419,Numbers34
29,535,2824,Proverbs19
29,524,2650,Proverbs22
29,494,2432,Psalms118
30,512,2659,Job22
30,507,2682,Job39
30,512,2595,Job6
30,943,4878,1Chronicles21
30,1018,5342,1Chronicles29
30,875,4481,1Samuel18
30,1012,5243,2Kings25
30,1022,5700,Daniel3
30,924,4593,Deuteronomy22
30,1071,5420,Deuteronomy31
30,783,4055,Exodus6
30,849,4235,Genesis38
30,893,4687,Isaiah5
30,867,4531,Jeremiah22
30,1258,6494,Jeremiah44
30,857,4543,Jeremiah6
30,1128,5636,Judges19
30,697,3807,Leviticus18
30,922,4739,Leviticus6
30,773,3897,Numbers23
30,528,2715,Proverbs20
31,545,2740,Job30
31,572,3171,1Chronicles24
31,574,3259,1Chronicles25
31,1018,5188,1Kings14
31,987,5109,1Samuel30
31,913,4787,2Chronicles9
31,1023,5194,2Samuel12
31,1026,5567,Daniel5
31,962,5011,Exodus14
31,821,4034,Exodus22
31,863,4631,Exodus38
31,922,4506,Exodus4
31,871,4586,Ezekiel22
31,989,5038,Ezekiel34
31,1062,5579,Ezekiel44
31,828,4203,Genesis1
31,821,4199,Genesis34
31,996,5109,Genesis47
31,789,4159,Isaiah1
31,827,4345,Isaiah40
31,892,4748,Jeremiah4
31,905,4740,Jeremiah5
31,1142,5767,Judges16
31,1066,5379,Judges18
31,873,4604,Judges3
31,786,4198,Judges5
31,993,5266,Nehemiah13
31,810,4217,Numbers28
31,929,4825,Numbers5
31,555,3061,Proverbs11
31,532,2822,Proverbs21
31,498,2604,Proverbs31
31,565,2879,Psalms109
31,611,3031,Psalms22
32,713,3782,1Chronicles23
32,742,4174,1Chronicles26
32,943,4937,2Samuel2
32,982,4949,Deuteronomy11
32,1087,5600,Deuteronomy12
32,1015,5469,Esther9
32,968,4952,Exodus8
32,951,5063,Ezekiel18
32,977,5002,Ezekiel21
32,1109,5664,Ezekiel32
32,527,2888,Genesis10
32,638,3344,Genesis11
32,826,4215,Genesis32
32,536,2867,Genesis5
32,888,4576,Isaiah14
32,1037,5482,Jeremiah29
32,1143,5823,Jeremiah36
32,990,5134,Joel2
32,928,5011,Nehemiah3
32,1144,6019,Numbers18
32,559,2946,Proverbs10
33,558,2851,Job33
33,528,2838,Job36
33,1071,5588,1Kings12
33,1117,5906,2Chronicles32
33,1256,6538,2Chronicles34
33,1052,5185,2Kings6
33,1150,5738,2Samuel14
33,1129,5748,2Samuel18
33,954,4747,Deuteronomy5
33,861,4438,Exodus23
33,1104,5585,Ezekiel33
33,900,4532,Genesis18
33,799,4159,Genesis49
33,1092,5571,Isaiah30
33,858,4794,Joshua13
33,1077,5504,Joshua24
33,952,4952,Leviticus15
33,912,4645,Leviticus22
33,774,3902,Numbers13
33,552,2899,Proverbs1
33,577,3076,Proverbs15
33,576,2969,Proverbs16
33,673,3400,Proverbs30
34,556,2869,Job21
34,541,2745,Job41
34,839,4574,1Chronicles27
34,1172,5671,1Kings13
34,985,5064,1Kings15
34,1069,5331,1Kings16
34,740,4001,1Kings4
34,1084,5577,2Chronicles18
34,740,3920,Genesis25
34,807,4090,Genesis21
34,972,4922,Genesis43
34,908,4453,Genesis44
34,800,4188,Genesis46
34,962,4889,Isaiah10
34,1108,5829,Jeremiah52
34,1004,5137,Jeremiah7
34,1355,7094,Joshua22
34,1191,6127,Leviticus16
34,990,5003,Leviticus27
34,862,4655,Numbers2
34,999,5172,Numbers35
34,614,3193,Proverbs24
35,584,3141,Job15
35,579,2901,Job9
35,1016,5268,1Samuel15
35,1128,5678,Exodus32
35,1040,5382,Exodus34
35,855,4526,Exodus35
35,1017,5125,Exodus9
35,1080,5651,Ezekiel48
35,923,4744,Genesis26
35,865,4397,Genesis29
35,1256,6296,Joshua8
35,1022,5306,Judges8
35,1192,6131,Leviticus4
35,1090,5570,Numbers11
35,966,5017,Numbers21
35,607,3175,Proverbs14
35,601,3069,Proverbs23
35,576,2968,Proverbs3
35,580,3054,Proverbs6
35,633,3272,Psalms104
35,733,3871,Psalms68
36,1140,5769,1Samuel2
36,1192,6429,2Chronicles29
36,1239,6274,2Kings10
36,1098,5527,Exodus16
36,929,4492,Exodus21
36,943,4999,Ezekiel27
36,1026,5349,Ezra8
36,978,4984,Genesis37
36,998,5389,Judges1
36,1023,5273,Leviticus8
36,824,4441,Nehemiah11
36,927,4766,Numbers10
36,598,3117,Proverbs8
36,705,3587,Psalms69
37,652,3403,Job34
37,1184,6343,2Chronicles20
37,1257,6464,2Kings18
37,1184,6169,2Kings19
37,1514,7843,2Kings23
37,1242,6191,2Kings9
37,1155,5924,2Samuel15
37,1327,6930,Daniel4
37,1058,5435,Deuteronomy2
37,974,5171,Exodus26
37,1056,5518,Jeremiah2
37,935,4807,Leviticus19
38,1056,5471,1Kings6
38,1130,5748,2Kings15
38,1008,5401,Exodus30
38,930,4952,Exodus36
38,859,4491,Exodus40
38,1218,6244,Ezekiel36
38,1146,5736,Genesis19
38,1015,5096,Genesis42
38,1169,6091,Isaiah37
38,1176,6111,Jeremiah25
38,1094,5710,Leviticus7
38,1366,7572,Nehemiah9
39,1188,6017,2Samuel13
39,917,4784,2Samuel23
39,1182,5997,2Samuel3
39,1219,6443,Jeremiah49
39,691,3813,Nehemiah10
40,731,3622,Job31
40,1027,5505,1Chronicles12
40,871,4796,1Chronicles7
40,531,2954,1Chronicles8
40,966,4953,Exodus25
40,1226,6391,Jeremiah23
40,1334,6875,Jeremiah31
40,1275,6657,Judges11
40,1335,6687,Judges6
40,994,5442,Numbers29
40,742,3833,Psalms37
41,700,3623,Job38
41,1286,6824,2Kings17
41,1109,5747,Numbers15
41,1242,6159,Numbers22
42,1331,6694,1Samuel20
42,1444,7585,2Chronicles6
42,1051,5592,Numbers32
43,893,4680,1Chronicles16
43,895,4895,1Chronicles4
43,1296,6754,1Kings11
43,1524,7819,1Kings20
43,1516,7548,2Samuel19
43,1278,6641,Exodus28
43,1073,5603,Exodus39
43,1065,5494,Genesis30
43,888,4715,Genesis36
43,1436,7450,Joshua10
43,728,3923,Psalms107
44,1004,5465,1Chronicles9
44,1496,7580,1Samuel25
44,1413,6821,2Kings4
44,968,5405,Ezra10
44,1476,7628,Jeremiah32
44,1266,6570,Leviticus23
45,1574,8250,Daniel11
45,1071,5731,Joshua21
45,1226,6428,Numbers14
45,677,3527,Psalms105
46,1443,7197,1Kings18
46,1556,7932,1Kings2
46,1308,6612,Deuteronomy1
46,1387,7102,Exodus29
46,1308,6459,Genesis27
46,1506,7957,Jeremiah50
46,1292,6623,Leviticus26
47,1000,5374,1Chronicles11
47,1220,6385,Jeremiah48
47,1162,6122,Leviticus11
47,977,5573,Nehemiah12
48,1503,7929,Judges20
48,810,4410,Psalms106
49,1549,8232,Daniel2
49,1552,8002,Deuteronomy4
49,1650,8407,Ezekiel20
49,1371,7482,Ezekiel23
49,1579,8284,Ezekiel40
49,1465,7916,Numbers4
50,1391,7296,Numbers16
50,968,4943,Psalms18
51,1535,8015,1Kings7
51,1002,5091,2Samuel22
51,1544,7882,Exodus12
51,995,5733,Joshua19
51,1342,7261,Numbers3
52,1658,8678,1Samuel14
52,1358,7011,Deuteronomy32
52,930,4807,Psalms89
53,1553,8080,1Kings1
53,1570,8045,1Kings22
54,737,4057,1Chronicles1
54,1387,7551,Numbers1
54,1262,6794,Numbers31
55,901,5024,1Chronicles2
55,1472,7563,Genesis31
55,1587,8034,Leviticus25
56,984,5520,Numbers33
57,1461,7448,Genesis41
57,1724,8892,Judges9
57,1770,8769,Leviticus14
58,1777,9086,1Samuel17
59,1917,9485,Leviticus13
63,1883,10180,Ezekiel16
63,1095,6049,Joshua15
64,1916,10110,Jeremiah51
65,1511,8384,Numbers26
66,2204,11622,1Kings8
66,942,4760,Lamentations3
67,1883,9440,Genesis24
68,2143,11136,Deuteronomy28
70,1068,6129,Ezra2
72,1297,6877,Psalms78
73,1249,7090,Nehemiah7
81,1422,7584,1Chronicles6
89,2028,10830,Numbers7
176,2599,13764,Psalms119
```

---

Notes (method used):

```
https://sites.google.com/site/ruwach/bibletext
OldTestament.zip 
find ./ -name *.txt | while read i; do wc "$i"; done > counts.csv
```

---

As noted in the comments above, there are some differences, for instance I Chron. Chapter 6 has 81 verses in KJV, versus 66 verses in Jewish versions.  [Conjecture: Christian version wanted to avoid having Ch. 6 have 66 verses due to 666?]

Comment: I'm missing something about this list. It's not sorted by chapter length, and Esther chapter 3 doesn't have two verses

Comment: @robev Maybe the KJV does?

Comment: Great. An answer about KJV on Mi Yodeya. Why is this question open?

Comment: I used the KJV for this analysis because the Mechon Mamre I downloaded is encoded in Windows-1255 not UTF-8 thus appears jarbled in my Linux terminal, plus contains html tags making counts more difficult.
Anyone know a nice zip of Tanakh in UTF-8 txt nicely formatted without tags?

Comment: @robev You're right, the zip contained a 16-chapter "Esther Greek" version.  Deleting those files and reposting results now..

Comment: You could probably download the Tanach in a useful format from Sefaria.